# f-string results in error with line breaks on CDSW/linux

Tags: python, linux, cdsw

I have a strange issue in python (3.6.1):

```
a = 3 
f"""a= {a}""" # works
```

But this does not on the Cloudera Data Science Workbench (a unix system):

```
f"""a=
{a}"""  # error

Engine, line 1
"
  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

On Windows I cannot recreate the problem and it did not use to be a problem on CDSW either. Has anyone had a similar problem or could point me towards what might cause such a problem?

---

Interestingly, this also works:

```
(f"""a=
{a}""")
```

To follow up on the comments:

```
my_frstring= f"""hello 
world {a}"""
for c in my_frstring:print(name(c))
LATIN SMALL LETTER H
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER L
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
SPACE
ValueError: no such name
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
in engine
----> 1 for c in my_frstring:print(name(c))

ValueError: no such name
```

Comment: Which python version is that? only python 3.6 >= versions support f-strings

Comment: it's working fine! **python3.7** or **newer**

Comment: Maybe you have an invisible character in the string.  Try doing `from unicodedata import name;for c in the_fstring:print(name(c))`

Comment: f-strings weren't added until Python 3.6 (see [What’s New In Python 3.6.14](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)). You can determine what version you have via `print(sys.version)`.

Comment: To get around the value error: `for c in the_fstring:print(ord(c))`